# C++ List of Pairs

Tags: c++, list, constructor, stl, std-pair

While getting comfortable with the C++ STL I ran into this issue using a list of pair objects.

```
int count (std::string input, std::vector<std::string> screen){

  std::string::iterator it = input.begin();

  std::pair<std::string, int> freq[10];
  std::list<std::pair<std::string,int>  > freq2;

  freq2.push_back(std::make_pair(*it,0)); //ERR:No instance of fn matches arg list 
  freq2.push_back(std::make_pair('S',0)); //ERR:No instance of fn matches arg list
  freq2.push_back(std::make_pair("S",0)); //This is fine

  freq[0] = std::make_pair(*it,0);        //This is fine
  freq[0] = std::make_pair("S",0);        //This is fine
  freq[0] = std::make_pair('S',0);        //This is fine

  return 1;

}
```

Both freq and freq2 are quite similar except freq2 is just a list. Freq is able to accept chars, strings, and the iterator pointer and both pairs (freq,freq2) are declared as  pairs. Not sure why this is happening, any tips? Thanks.

edit: It makes a lot more sense now, all the responses I got were really helpful, thank you guys!

Comment: which compiler are you using......... i am getting a different set of errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class `std::basic_string` has no constructor that has one parameter of type `char`.So these statemenets are invalid

```
  freq2.push_back(std::make_pair(*it,0)); //ERR:No instance of fn matches arg list 
  freq2.push_back(std::make_pair('S',0)); //ERR:No instance of fn matches arg list
```

Speaking more precisely in these statements there is an attempt to build an object of type `std::pair<std::string, int>` from an object of type `std::pair<char, int>`. This requires that there would be a constructor of class `std::string` that has parameter of type `char`. However there is no such a constructor.

As for these statements

```
  freq[0] = std::make_pair(*it,0);        //This is fine
  freq[0] = std::make_pair('S',0);        //This is fine
```

then there is used an assignment operator of class `std::basic_string`. The class has an overloaded assignment operator that accepts an object of type `char`.

```
basic_string& operator=(charT c);
```

So these statements are correct.

Consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std::pair<std::string, int> p1 = { "a", 1 };
    std::pair<char, int> p2 = { 'B', 2 };

    p1 = p2;

    std::cout << p1.first << '\t' << p1.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
B   2
```

As class `std::pair` has a template assignment operator and class `std::string` in turn has assignment operator that has parameter of type char then this code is compiled successfully.

If you would write for example

```
std::pair<std::string, int> p1 = std::make_pair( 'a', 1 );
```

instead of

```
    std::pair<std::string, int> p1 = { "a", 1 };
```

you would get an error because there is no conversion from `std::pair<char, int>` to `std::pair<std::string, int>` because there is no constructor from `char` to `std::string`.

Comment: But for the second set of statements, doesn't std::make_pair have to construct the object first before it will be reassigned to the pair in freq?

Comment: @David Tr It constructs an object of type std::pair<char, int>.

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense now, your example after the fact made sense. I didn't know the assignment operator worked like that on a pair object. Good explanation.

Answer (score 5):

There is no implicit constructor in `std::string` that accepts `char` and can be used to convert type `char` to `std::string`. What you can use is this constructor:

> basic_string( size_type count, 
>                 CharT ch, 
>                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

so

```
freq2.push_back(std::make_pair( std::string( 1, *it ),0));
```

and so on

Comment: @YZ.learner Because, for some reason, there is an assignment-operator that accepts a single character on the rhs.

Comment: To elaborate, the call in `freq2` is using constructors. The call in `freq` is using the default constructor and then the assignment operator.

Comment: @dyp There is no "signle character" on the rhs. [make_pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) returns a `std::pair`

Comment: @YZ.learner: Internally, the pair will use `operator=` when making the assignment.

Comment: @YZ.learner: Note the difference between: `std::pair<std::string, int> fails('S', 0);` and `std::pair<std::string, int> works; works = std::make_pair('S', 0);`.

Comment: @sharth, Well, I guess my question then would be why can you assign an object of type `std::pair<std::string, int>` to a value of type `std::pair<char, int>`

Comment: @YZ.learner: Because it has an assignment operator that looks like this: [`std::pair<T1, T2> = std::pair<U1, U2>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator%3D), the lhs and rhs don't have to be the same types. We just require that we can do `T1 = U1` and `T2 = U2`.

Comment: Please add this to your answer. +1

Comment: I like that explanation @sharth

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're attempting to construct a `std::string` from a single char.  There is no such constructor for `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing char and std::string types. String iterators point to individual char values, not a std::string. Review http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/ for details.

Also, `'S'` is NOT equivilent to `"S"` as the first is of type char while the second is a of type char* which points to an address in memory which contains a `'S'` followed by a `'\0'`(the "null character" which is NOT the same as null).

```
freq2.push_back(std::make_pair(*it,0)); //The iterator is pointing to a literal character value, and not a string
freq2.push_back(std::make_pair('S',0)); //This is a literal character, and not a string literal
freq2.push_back(std::make_pair("S",0)); //This is fine and what you intended
```

The assignments to the array do so via an implicit conversion. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/ .

```
freq[0] = std::make_pair(*it,0);        //Implicit conversion from Pair<char, int>
freq[0] = std::make_pair("S",0);        //Implicit conversion from Pair<char*, int>
freq[0] = std::make_pair('S',0);        //Implicit conversion from Pair<char, int>
```

A *potential* work around if you actually **need** this conversion functionality would be to create a variable of type `std::pair<std::string, int>` and then pushing the value onto the list. I would only recommend this in a desperate and odd case though, and instead correct the intent of the code directly.